# How to fix corrplot formatting issue in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis, r-corrplot

When I run the following chunk of code, I get a very small and unuseful correlation plot(see photo). I think it is because the column labels are too large. Is there any suggestion on how to fix this issue without modifying column names (maybe indicating only substring of names for example...)

```
numeric.var <- sapply(df_train, is.numeric)
corr.matrix <- cor(df_train[,numeric.var])
corrplot(corr.matrix, main="\n\nCorrelation Plot for Numerical Variables", 
method="number")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, could you please share your data using `dput(df_train)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: One solution might be just writing it to a bigger device.  For example, if you did `png("corplot.png", height=20, width=20, units="in")` before the plotting function and then `dev.off()` after, that will write the `.png` to your working directory and generally larger devices will have smaller text, symbols, etc...

Comment: It's not working, but it might be because I am not understanding how to apply what you told me to do